# What is the relationship between Steppenwolf and Darkseid?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017

In the DC universe what is the relation between Steppenwolf and Darkseid?

In the movie *Justice League*, we see Steppenwolf mention Darksied in one of his speeches. Also the flying creatures, I believe, are part of Darkseid's army.

Comment: Husband and wife.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steppenwolf is Darkseid's uncle, the brother of Darkseid's mother Queen Heggra.  Darkseid arranged to get Steppenwolf killed in the original war between New Genesis and Apokalips, to help clear the way to Darkseid's taking ultimate power on Apokalips.  Once his position was secure, Darkseid resurrected his uncle, who had served since then, primarily as the commander of the Apokalips dog cavalry.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to consider this the answer without clarifying comics vs film information, considering that the question is entirely about the films. There have been media reports that the characters' relationship was switched, with Darkseid being Steppenwolf's uncle, and other reports that this is not the case. Their relationship is not mentioned at all in the film, so one can't assume the comics information is canon for the film without a statement from the filmmakers.